# TFS Team Build with VSO - Git Commit/Push files that have been altered by the build process

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, azure-devops, git-push, git-commit

I have created a build definition that uses the Default Template(GitTemplate.12.xaml). I have a Pre-Build Script that updates the version numbers for all of the assemblies in the build.

I would like to be able to commit and push the files that have been altered by the build definition to the git repository.

I have tried doing this using a PowerShell script but was not able to do this because Git with VSO requires that you pass in user credentials.

I have downloaded the template to see if I can customise it to complete this task but can see no obvious way of solving my problem.

My next step will be to investigate writing a custom piece of code that can be called by the template.Just wanted to find out before I delve into this any deeper if I am wasting my time.

I am using VSO and VS2013.

Does anybody have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not commit those changes as it allows a developer to build an identical version numbered assembly locally.It is not a good practice to push the results back into Source Control.

You should set all of your assemblyinfo.* files to 0.0.0.0 and push. Then the only way for your assemblies to get a "good" version number is through the build process.

If you do want to go ahead you will need to authenticate using the "alternative" credentials that you can get from your profile page.

Comment: This should be a comment : you're opening the debate of the "Why" and are not giving any solution for the "How". We can discuss about the "Why" but the "How" is definitely a good question.